# Account for floating point imprecision when testing "approximately greater than"

Tags: floating-point

Let's say I want to check whether two numbers `a` and `b` are equal. Because of imprecision with floating points, I know that instead of simply checking `a == b`, I usually want to pick some small number `eps` and check instead that `abs(a - b) < eps`.

But what do I do if I want to take into account floating point errors when checking that `a > b`? I'm guessing that instead of simply

```
if (a > b) {
  ...
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
if ((a > b) || abs(a - b) < eps) {
  ...
}
```

Is this correct? How do I check that `a` is "approximately greater than" `b`?

Comment: “I know that instead of simply checking a == b, I usually want to pick some small number eps” What you should know is that you want to understand the logic of your program and use this knowledge to pick an appropriate epsilon, **if any is needed**. The same understanding will lead you to the right decision for `a>b`. There is no general solution for `a==b` (you can complain to whomever told you there was), and there is no general solution for `a>b`.

Comment: It's impossible to answer a question like this without knowing more about the application.  E.g., with `if (a > b - eps)`, which is equivalent to your second `if` statement, you'll get some false positives.  Whether those false positives are acceptable for your particular application is impossible to gauge without further information.

Comment: The use of an `epsilon` may not be sufficient, since the correct choice of an epsilon depends on the relative magnitudes involved. It's definitely worth looking at these issues in depth. [Goldberg's paper](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf) is a classic, and heavy on theory. There's also a good series of articles [here](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking how to calculate a correct result (whether one value is greater than another value) from incorrect input (some values that have errors in them). Obviously, this is impossible in general: Incorrect input produces incorrect output. However, in some specific situations, we can salvage something. The following discusses one situation.

Let’s suppose you have calculated some `a` and `b` that approximate the ideal values *a* and *b*, where *a* and *b* are the results you would have if the calculations were done with exact mathematics. Also suppose that we know error bounds *e<sub>a</sub>* and *e<sub>b</sub>* such that *a* – *e<sub>a</sub>* ≤ `a` ≤ *a* + *e<sub>a</sub>* and *a* – *e<sub>b</sub>* ≤ `b` ≤ *b* + *e<sub>b</sub>*. In other words, the calculated `a` and `b` lie within some intervals around *a* and *b*, respectively. (Depending on the operations performed, it is possible that errors could cause `a` or `b` to lie in some unconnected intervals, possibly not even containing *a* or *b*. But we will suppose you have “well behaved” errors.)

In that case, if `a` – *e<sub>a</sub>* > `b` + *e<sub>b</sub>*, then you can be certain that *a* > *b*.

However, suppose you test for this condition and return `true` if it holds. Then, whenever this returns `true`, you will know that *a* > *b*. However, when it returns `false`, you will not be sure that *a* > *b* is false. So, this test is good if you want to perform some action **only** when you are **certain** that *a* > *b*. But this causes you to miss performing the action in some cases when *a* > *b*.

Suppose you do not want to miss any of those cases. Then consider the condition `a` + *e<sub>a</sub>* > `b` – *e<sub>b</sub>*. If *a* > *b*, then this condition must be true. So, if you test for this condition and perform the desired action when it holds, then the action will **always** be performed when *a* > *b*. However, the action may also be performed some times when it is not true that *a* > *b*.

This shows that you have choices to make. If you have errors in your calculations, sometimes your application will do the wrong thing. You must choose:

- How acceptable it is for your application to perform the action when it is false that *a* > *b*. Is it always acceptable/unacceptable, or does it depend on how close *a* is to *b*?
- How acceptable it is for your application to not perform the action when it is true that *a* > *b*. Is it always acceptable/unacceptable, or does it depend on how close *a* is to *b*?

If you can find some satisfactory compromise, then you set your condition to some intermediate level, and you test for the condition `a-b > e`, for some `e` that lies between – *e<sub>a</sub>* – *e<sub>b</sub>* and + *e<sub>a</sub>* + *e<sub>b</sub>*, inclusive. If you cannot find a satisfactory compromise, then you need to improve the calculations of `a` and `b` to reduce the errors, or you need to redesign your program in some way.

Note: The final test in this scenario is `a-b > e` rather than `a > b+e` because there may be a small rounding error calculating `b+e`. There may also be a rounding error calculating `a-b`, but only if `a` and `b` are not near each other, in which case the difference, even with rounding, is much larger than `e` (unless your error interval is atrocious). In the cases where we care about precision, when `a` is near `b`, the calculation of `a-b` is exact.